# How to change ul - list-style-image in Weebly.

Tags: html, css, html-lists, weebly

I got a problem by creating page on Weebly. So when I modify my 'ul' tag like this:

```
#top-home-wrap #main #content ul {
color: yellow;
list-style-image: url('fa-check.png') !important;
}
```

It doesn't work because it is using some default theme styles. How to fix this problem?

Comment: You need to specify li for image as well. #top-home-wrap #main #content ul li{}
check the path of image in your css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your default style is applied over the `li` instead `ul`. So try this:

```
#top-home-wrap #main #content ul li{
   color: yellow;
   list-style-image: url('fa-check.png') !important;
}
```